# Loop selection with increment using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am facing the following issue:

If I have the following XML data:

```
<Input>
  <Error>
    <Info> 
      <Code> 111 </Code> 
      <Value>Hello User </Value>
    </Info>
    <Info> 
      <Code>118</Code> 
      <Value>01</Value>
    </Info>
  </Error>
  <Error>
    <Info> 
      <Code> 111 </Code> 
      <Value>Bye User </Value>
    </Info>
    <Info> 
      <Code>118</Code> 
      <Value>01</Value>
    </Info>
  </Error>
  <Error>
    <Info> 
      <Code> 111 </Code> 
      <Value>Dead User </Value>
    </Info>
    <Info> 
      <Code>118</Code> 
      <Value>06</Value>
    </Info>
  </Error>
  <Error>
    <Info> 
      <Code> 111 </Code> 
      <Value>Killed User </Value>
    </Info>
    <Info> 
      <Code>118</Code> 
      <Value>08</Value>
    </Info>
  </Error>
</Input>
```

How can I build an XSLT transform for the above, knowing that the output should be something like

```
<RecNum>"Value found inside VALUE[2]"</RecNum>
<Error-Description> "Value found inside Value[1]" </Error-Description>
```

Please note that it is not always that I have the same output. What I am sure of is that in every `Error` element I have 2 `Info` elements and 2 `Value` elements every time.

Yet, I don't know how many `Error` elements I have within the same `Value[2]`, so Sometimes I have 3 `Error` elements, all of them with 2 `Info` tags, but those three errors, their `Info[2]/Value/text()` is the same.

So an output for the above input should be something like this

```
<Errors>
  <Module>
    <RecNum>1 </RecNum>
    <Error-Description>Hello user </Error-Description>
    <Error-Description>By User </Error-Description>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <RecNum>6 </RecNum>
    <Error-Description> Dead User </Error-Description>
  </Module>
  <Module>
    <RecNum>8 </RecNum>
    <Error-Description> Killed User </Error-Description>
  </Module>
</Errors>
```

Note that I didn't have a Value of 02, 03, 04, 05, 07, 09, etc ...

I only had values for 01, 06 & 08 sometimes these might differ. How can such a logic be done if you please ?

Answer (score 3):

**I recommend to try to avoid `xsl:for-each` in favor of the truly XSLT in spirit use of templates**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kErrorByVal" match="Error" use="*[2]/Value"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
     <Errors>
       <xsl:apply-templates select=
       "*[generate-id()=generate-id(key('kErrorByVal',*[2]/Value)[1])]"/>
     </Errors>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Error">
  <Module>
   <RecNum><xsl:value-of select="*[2]/Value"/></RecNum>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kErrorByVal',*[2]/Value)/*[1]/Value"/>
  </Module>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Value">
  <Error-Description><xsl:value-of select="."/></Error-Description>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Input>
  <Error>
    <Info>
      <Code> 111 </Code>
      <Value>Hello User </Value>
    </Info>
    <Info>
      <Code>118</Code>
      <Value>01</Value>
    </Info>
  </Error>
  <Error>
    <Info>
      <Code> 111 </Code>
      <Value>Bye User </Value>
    </Info>
    <Info>
      <Code>118</Code>
      <Value>01</Value>
    </Info>
  </Error>
  <Error>
    <Info>
      <Code> 111 </Code>
      <Value>Dead User </Value>
    </Info>
    <Info>
      <Code>118</Code>
      <Value>06</Value>
    </Info>
  </Error>
  <Error>
    <Info>
      <Code> 111 </Code>
      <Value>Killed User </Value>
    </Info>
    <Info>
      <Code>118</Code>
      <Value>08</Value>
    </Info>
  </Error>
</Input>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<Errors>
   <Module>
      <RecNum>01</RecNum>
      <Error-Description>Hello User </Error-Description>
      <Error-Description>Bye User </Error-Description>
   </Module>
   <Module>
      <RecNum>06</RecNum>
      <Error-Description>Dead User </Error-Description>
   </Module>
   <Module>
      <RecNum>08</RecNum>
      <Error-Description>Killed User </Error-Description>
   </Module>
</Errors>
```

Answer (score 0):

This stylesheet uses a key to identify all `Error` nodes that have the same `Info[2]/Value`. This is known as the *Muenchian* method.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:key name="error-by-code" match="Error" use="Info[2]/Value"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Errors>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Input/Error"/>
    </Errors>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Error">
    <xsl:variable name="error-code" select="Info[2]/Value"/>
    <xsl:if test="generate-id() = generate-id(key('error-by-code', $error-code)[1])">
      <Module>
        <RecNum>
          <xsl:value-of select="Info[2]/Value"/>
        </RecNum>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('error-by-code', $error-code)">
          <Error-Description>
            <xsl:value-of select="Info[1]/Value"/>
          </Error-Description>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </Module>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Errors>
   <Module>
      <RecNum>01</RecNum>
      <Error-Description>Hello User </Error-Description>
      <Error-Description>Bye User </Error-Description>
   </Module>
   <Module>
      <RecNum>06</RecNum>
      <Error-Description>Dead User </Error-Description>
   </Module>
   <Module>
      <RecNum>08</RecNum>
      <Error-Description>Killed User </Error-Description>
   </Module>
</Errors>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same method without any ifs and variables. It checks all error values and group them. The second for-each selects only the needed Strings in the second Info tag.

This method should be a fast way to solve the problem

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:key name="errors-by-id" match="Error" use="Info[2]/Value" />
        <xsl:template match="Input">
            <xsl:for-each select="Error[count(. | key('errors-by-id', Info[2]/Value)[1]) = 1]">
                <xsl:sort select="Info[2]/Value" />
                <Modul>
                    <RecNum>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Info[2]/Value" />
                    </RecNum>
                <xsl:for-each select="key('errors-by-id', Info[2]/Value)">
                    <Error-Description>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Info[1]/Value"/>
                    </Error-Description>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </Modul>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template> 
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: pad, This doesn't produce exactly the wanted result. You need at least two more lines of code. Also, using `count()` and the union operator to determine node identity is most often less-efficient than using `generate-id()`. Finally, using `xsl:for-each` -- (what is more, even nested) results in rather messy, more difficult to understand and maintain code. Using templates -- the fundamental feature of XSLT -- fixes all these issues.